# I create a menu(Home, My Quote, Send a Quote) using <fb:tab>

Tags: php, facebook

can any body help me the
 create a menu(Home, My Quote, Send a Quote) using  for my facebook application. When I select a tab, the menu disappears when a new page opens up. I need to display my page under the menu itself, so how to do that

the code is

```
  <div>
    <fb:tabs>
      <fb:tab-item href="http://apps.facebook.com/ranpariya/index.php" title="Home"      
      <?php if ($page == 'index.php'):?>selected="true"<?php endif;?>/>
   <fb:tab-item href="http://apps.facebook.com/ranpariya/friends.php" title="Friends" <?php if ($page == 'friends.php'):?>selected="true"<?php endif;?>/>
    <fb:tab-item href="http://apps.facebook.com/ranpariya/my_tab.php" title="Invite Friends" align="right" <?php if ($page == 'invite.php'):?>selected="true"<?php endif;?>/>
    </fb:tabs>
  </div>
```

Comment: sounds very strange - are you sure you have it included in all the other pages? 

if yes take a look at the generated source maybe there is a minor parsing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a `DIV` under the menu and change it's `innerHTML` (or, if using jQuery, call `$("#myDiv").html(sHtml);`) with different content, based on the command selected.

Comment: hello friend , already i have to put menu under the div tab, but there is no making any effect,
the menu disappears when a click on the any tab

Comment: What I mean is, have a separate DIV element, name it "content". Catch the tab click event. Upon click, change the HTML of content to the HTML you'd ike to see under that tab.

Comment: can u give me an example of it